Finding how to turn a image into the link
In previous steps you used an anchor element to turn text into a link. Other types of content can also be turned into a link by wrapping it in anchor tags.
Turn the image into a link by surrounding it with necessary element tags. Use https://freecatphotoapp.com as the anchor's href attribute value.
I tried to put (a) anchor tag in the image link

You should tell us whats your problem and enclose some code what you did.

"I tried to put (a) anchor tag in the image link" - Yes, that's the correct approach. The content of the href attribute is pretty much irrelevant as long as it's a valid URL. Can you please edit the question and share your HTML code? You can use the {} (Code Sample) toolbar button to format it or, even better, the <> (HTML snippet) to create a live version of the code that we can all run.

This sounds like homework. only the last sentence comes from you, the rest is of the text is coming from the assignment?


Turn the image into a link by surrounding it with necessary element tags. Use https://freecatphotoapp.com as the anchor's href attribute value.

<a href="https://freecatphotoapp.com">
  <img src="https://somesite.com/catphoto.png">
</a>

if your hosting the server, the img src can be a relative path that starts from where the html file is stored './catphoto.png' or a relative path beginning from the servers public document root such as '/images/catphoto.png'
